# How do i read response body of plain text from an api and covert or serialize into an object in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Am trying to read a a returned  tab plaint text from a wsdl service built with an xpath. How can i deserialize it into and object or convert it into an object in .net core 2.0. Am using the .net core inbuilt wcf service reference  to talk to the wsdl service.

this is my code snippet from the controller level

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateModelVm date)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if(date.PfaId == 21)
                    {
                        var depositVm = _DepositeModelPass.MapDepositeModelVmToModelVm(date, ICredentials._currentStanbicAccountNumber, ICredentials._currentStanbicCustomerId, ICredentials._currentzenithpasssowrd, ICredentials._currentzenithuserName);

                        var Mappedresult = _DepositeModelPass.MapDepositeModelVmToModel(depositVm);
            //fetch deposit from Servce
                        var ReturnedResult = await _depositService.getDepositsAsync(Mappedresult);



                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnedResult.Body.result))
                        {

                            // create folder path
                            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                            // create directory
                            var directoryname = ProcessFile.CreateDirectory(webRootPath);



                            //create  write into text file
                            await ProcessFile.CreateAndWriteToTextFile(directoryname, ReturnedResult.Body.result);



                            List<DepositModel> processedDeposit = CsvMapper.DepositModelParser(directoryname);
}
```

this is the code for writing to text file

```
 public static async Task CreateAndWriteToTextFile(string myCurrentDirectoryName, string body)
        {
            //check if file exist in the folder created

            try
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(myCurrentDirectoryName))
                {

                    await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(myCurrentDirectoryName + "//" + stanbicFile, body);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

fetching from text file using csvhelper library to convert to an object

```
 public static List<DepositModel> DepositModelParser(string directoryName)
        {
            string path = directoryName + "\\" + "xxxx.txt";
            List<DepositModel> depositModels = new List<DepositModel>();
            // read from file
            using (StreamReader str = System.IO.File.OpenText(path))
            using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(str))
            {
                IEnumerable<DepositModel> deposits = csvReader.GetRecords<DepositModel>();
                csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
                csvReader.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
                csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DepositeModelMap>();
                csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;


                foreach (var item in deposits)
                {
                    var depo = new DepositModel()
                    {
                        AccountNumber = item.AccountNumber,
                        Amount = item.Amount,
                        Branch = item.Branch,
                        City = item.City,
                        Country = item.Country,
                        Currency = item.Currency,
                        DepositSlipNumber = item.DepositSlipNumber,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        FirstName = item.FirstName,
                        FundId = item.FundId,
                        LastName = item.LastName,
                        OtherName = item.OtherName,
                        PaymentMethod = item.PaymentMethod,
                        PFACode = item.PFACode,
                        PFAName = item.PFAName,
                        ReversalNumber = item.ReversalNumber,
                        RSAPin = item.RSAPin,
                        TransactionDate = item.TransactionDate,
                        TransactionNumber = item.TransactionNumber,
                        ValueDate = item.ValueDate

                    };
                    depositModels.Add(depo);

                }
            }
}
```

this is the the plain text result gotten from the wsdl after writing to text file

```
Transaction No. Transaction Date Value Date Description Amount Currency Branch City Country Reversal No. Payment Method Deposit Slip No RSA PIN First Name Last Name Other Name PFA Code PFA Name Fund ID Account No
68663XXX 2019-09-10 11:35:24 2019-09-10 XXXX110003XXXX/TEXXX/NYXXX/028/DS 76026 CD K INNOVATIVE 500.00 NGN Eagle Abuja NGR   0   76026 XXX110003XXXX TERKIMBI NYIEYEM   028 TRUSTXXX_XXXX 16 10163XXXX
d639164fe718df68c18aacbXXX​
```

[returned result from service snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DraME.png)

Is there a way i can read this file directly and convert to an object without using csv helper library and without writing to textfile when gotten from the wsdl service...

Comment: Hi tmax!  Can you show us what you already have tried?  Are you able to get the plain text into a string variable?  And if so, what kind of content is the string? XML? JSON? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the swift responds  at caseyCrookston. am currently out of the office, i will send sample code tomorrow. but the content is not really XML or Jason its jut plain text content separated by tabs. That is what the service is returning, that is what a trying to convert to an object so i can assign to my model.

Comment: Ok, so are you able to get the tab-separated text into a string variable?

Comment: Yes at caseycrookston. i was able to get it into a string variable, i was also able to write it into a text file as well.

Comment: Ok! So your real question is: How do I deserialize a tab-delimited string to an object? :-)  It would be very helpful if you can show us the string, and show us the object you want to create from it.

Comment: at Casey Crookston am sorry for the delay, have edited the question and added what i have done so far. Is their a way i can read those string from the service and deserialize into an object without writing to text file at first and also using csv helper to convert to object.

Comment: Hi tmax noda, so for you to be able to deserialize this text to an object you have to use some method to add some logic to how the deserliaztion will perform, if you don't want to perform that kind of logic and you have the option to change the input i recommend a json file is way easier and more simple and structured

Comment: Can i convert plain text to a Json? If so, how do i do that. Remember the Plaintext is coming directly from the returned result from the wsdl service.

Comment: and again, the service is said to be a SAOP. I was expecting XML as a returned result but i can only find tab separated strings value. again am taking to this wsdl service using the inbuilt WCF  service in visual studio not HttpClient this time.

Comment: I think you mean SOAP and not SAOP.  SOAP stands for Simple Object Access Protocol.  And SOAP *always* uses XML.  The string, as you are showing us, is going to be pretty much impossible to do anything with.  But when you first receive the data, it IS going to be in XML.  Let me look over your code and see if I can figure out why you are getting it as a plain string, and not as XML.  (Also, as a side note, it would really help us help you if you could respond more qickly!!! When days go by with no response, we forget about this.)

Comment: Ok, we are going to need to see what is inside of `getDepositsAsync` from `var ReturnedResult = await _depositService.getDepositsAsync(Mappedresult);`  It looks like by the time you call that method, the contents of `ReturnedResult.Body.result` have already been stripped of the original, raw XML and turned into the string you are showing us.

Comment: have added the snapshot for the returned result from the service, you can take a look sir.